# Integration along the side in isoparametric quadrilateral mapping

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, chain-rule, quadrilateral, lagrange-interpolation

I need to integrate a function (say,$F(x,y)=x^3+y^3$) along one side of the given quadrilateral. For example, the $ x $ and $ y$ coordinate of the quadrilateral are$ (0,0),(2,-1),(3,2),(1,3)$ and the concerned line is, the line joining $(2,-1)$ and $(3,2)$.

These  are the steps which I followed,

**1) INTEGRATING GEOMETRIC INTERPOLATION**

1. Given quadrilateral is mapped into a standard square (of coordinates$(-1,-1),(1,-1),(1,1),(-1,1)$ in (s,t) ) by isoparametric mapping.
2. From  Lagrangian interpolation $ X(s,t)= \sum N_ix_i$ and $Y(s,t)=\sum N_ix_i$ 
   Where $N_1=(1-s)(1-t)/4,\ N_2=(1+s)(1-t)/4,\ N_3=(1+s)(1+t)/4 \  \ \ \  and \\  N_4=(1-s)(1+t)/4$ Hence,
   $$X(s,t)=(3(s + 1)(t + 1))/4 - ((s + 1)(t - 1))/2 - ((s - 1)(t + 1))/4 $$
   $$Y(s,t)=((s + 1)(t - 1))/4 - (3(s - 1)*(t + 1))/4 + ((s + 1)(t + 1))/2$$
3. Along the given side $\ dl=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ and   $ \ dl=\ \sqrt{(dX/dt)^2+(dY/dt)^2}\  \  dt$
4. Hence $$\int_{(2,-1)}^{(3,2)} x^3+y^3 \ dl =\int_{-1}^1 (X(1,t)^3+Y(1,t)^3) \sqrt{(dX/dt)^2+(dY/dt)^2}\  \  dt $$

Unfortunately, I get wrong integration result when I mapped my original quadrilateral into the standard square. Where did I make mistake in the integration?

**2) LINE INTEGRAL CALCULATION**
$$\int_{(2,-1)}^{(3,2)}\ x^3+y^3 \ dl\ =\ \sqrt(10)\  \int_{0}^1\ {(m+2)}^3+(3m-1)^3 \ dm$$

**3) INTEGRATING ELEMENT VARIABLE INTERPOLATION**

1. $F_i(x_i,y_i)=\ x_i^3 +y_i^3$ is calculated at 4 points.
2. At any point in  the standard square, function $F(x,y)$ is approximated as
   $$ \hat{F}(s,t)=\ \sum_{n=1}^4 N_iF_i(x_i,y_i)$$
   $N_i$   is Lagrangian shape function for standard square.
3. So the required integral is,
   $$\int_{(2,-1)}^{(3,2)}\ x^3+y^3 \ dl\ =\ \int_{-1}^1 \hat{F}(s,t) \sqrt{(dX/dt)^2+(dY/dt)^2}\  \  dt $$

**RESULTS**
The first and second  methods gives the exact result $(55.3399)$ while third method gives $66.407$. The error in the third method is expected since the degree of interpolation function is less than that of real function.

**PROBLEM**
How do I get an accurate result from the integration of interpolation function of element variable (i.e by doing third method)? Is this related to subparametric mapping?

Comment: You're using variable $s$ twice with different meanings (in $ds$ and in $X(s, t)$, for example). Also, what are $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt? You've defined only $X(t,s), Y(t,s)$.

Comment: @uranix, edited the question again.

Comment: What values do you obtain for the integrals? Also how do you compute the line integral?

Comment: @uranix, Both results are added, and error is increasing, if higher order function is integrated

Comment: $$\sqrt{10} \int_0^1 (m+2)^3 + (3m-1)^3 dm = \frac{35\sqrt{10}}{2} \approx 55.3399,$$ so both seem to give the same result

Comment: @uranix, But the other integral gives 66.407

Comment: $$
\int_{-1}^1 \left(X(1,t)^3+Y(1,t)^3\right) \sqrt{X_t^2(1,t)+Y_t^2(1,t)} dt = \frac{35\sqrt{10}}{2}
$$

Comment: @uranix, sorry for late reply. Could you please look at the question again?

Comment: You approximate a bicubic polynomial $\tilde F(s,t) = F(X(s,t),Y(s,t))$ with a bilinear one $\hat F(s,t)$, this is the origin of the difference

Comment: @uranix, Yes, I understood it. Shall I have to add more  nodes in order to make the interpolation function cubic? or Could you suggest any other simple method? (I'm very beginner in computational science)

Comment: Is $x^3 + y^3$ the typical function you need to integrate?

Comment: @uranix No, I took it as an example. I need to interpolate a function of maximum degree 6 ( degree of polynomial may change)